# GDB: Can't debug gcc/gcov

Tags: linux, gcc, gdb, debug-symbols, gcov

I am using gcov to gather coverage information of my C project. However, there are certain files for which there's no coverage data(gcda files) generated although they have been executed in my tests.

I wanted to find out the reasons by debugging the gcov/gcc source. To be precise, I want to debug the method **__gcov_flush()** step by step to see what's happening. I am not entirely sure where this method resides. I think it's libgcov.o file residing in libgcov.a library which is part of gcc.

When I tried to debug the code initially, GDB reported that it can't find debug symbols. So, I installed debuginfo for gcc and libgcc. However, even after installing those two debuginfo files, GDB still reports it can't find **libgcov.c**.

```
opensuse12:/usr/Cpro/gcov_example # gdb -q ./a.out
Reading symbols from /usr/Cpro/gcov_example/a.out...done.
(gdb)
(gdb) break __gcov_flush
Breakpoint 1 at 0x402820: file ../../../libgcc/libgcov.c, line 734.
(gdb) r
Starting program: /usr/Cpro/gcov_example/a.out
Breakpoint 1, __gcov_flush () at ../../../libgcc/libgcov.c:734
734     ../../../libgcc/libgcov.c: No such file or directory.
(gdb)
(gdb) info source
Current source file is ../../../libgcc/libgcov.c
Compilation directory is /home/abuild/rpmbuild/BUILD/gcc-4.7.1-20120723/obj-x86_64-suse-linux/x86_64-suse-linux/libgcc
Source language is c.
Compiled with DWARF 2 debugging format.
Does not include preprocessor macro info.
(gdb) show directories
Source directories searched: $cdir:$cwd
```

If I try to debug gcc/gcov directly, GDB properly identifies the debuginfo files.

```
opensuse12:/usr/Cpro/gcov_example # gdb -q gcc
Reading symbols from /usr/bin/gcc...Reading symbols from /usr/lib/debug/usr/bin/gcc-4.7.debug...done.
done.
(gdb) break __gcov_flush
Function "__gcov_flush" not defined.
Make breakpoint pending on future shared library load? (y or [n]) n
(gdb) q
opensuse12:/usr/Cpro/gcov_example #
opensuse12:/usr/Cpro/gcov_example # gdb -q gcov
Reading symbols from /usr/bin/gcov...Reading symbols from /usr/lib/debug/usr/bin/gcov-4.7.debug...done.
done.
(gdb) break __gcov_flush
Function "__gcov_flush" not defined.
Make breakpoint pending on future shared library load? (y or [n]) n
(gdb) q
```

Note that GDB is reading the symbols from proper locations:

**Reading symbols from /usr/lib/debug/usr/bin/gcc-4.7.debug...done.**

**Reading symbols from /usr/lib/debug/usr/bin/gcov-4.7.debug...done.**

But still reports that **Function "__gcov_flush" not defined** and **../../../libgcc/libgcov.c: No such file or directory**.

What else am I missing? Shouldn't libgcov.c be part of gcc-debuginfo file? What else needs to be installed.

I am using openSuSE 12.2. Both gcc and gcov are at 4.7.1 version.

Comment: it seems that gdb can find the symbol but failed to locate the source file. what's your source path setting?  try " show directories "

Comment: I have updates my post. Please see "info source" and "show directories" output in first code section. Now I have two questions. (1) It says it was compiled with DWARF 2 debugging format, but shows no source. (2) Why do we need source when we have an executable with debug symbols ?

Comment: you should debug your program instead of gcc/gcov. __gcov_flush is the function called by your binary when it exits.

Comment: Yes, that's what I am doing. See the first block with command "gdb -q ./a.out". It reports "libgcov.c: No such file or directory"

Comment: files containing debug symbols include things like the types of variables and object-location-to-source-file mappings; they do not include the text of the source code. If you want to debug using the source code for `libgcov.c`, you'll need to download the source code for gcc 4.7.1 (possibly by typing `zypper si gcc47`, if OpenSUSE has that available in its repositories)

Comment: pls locate file libgcov.c on your host and if it doesn't exist you would need to install the src rpm

Comment: I now understood that I need source along with debuginfo. Strangely however, installing both gcc & libgcc sources from SuSE repos still don't give me the necessary libgcov.c file. I don't know why. And I couldn't find gcc4.7.1(and thus libgcov.c 4.7.1) source on Google.

Comment: I was able to find it here: http://mirrors.zerg.biz/gnu/gcc/gcc-4.7.1/

Comment: The above solved my issue. However, I got another problem. When I tried to debug the same on other machine SLES 10, GDB can not even idenitfy line number information. And hence having the gcc source is not helping. GDB simply steps to next line even though I asked it to step into. This behavior is explained here : https://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Continuing-and-Stepping.html . But I don't know what to do to make GDB line info available.